# JavaFX how to return to state where waiting for user event

Tags: events, groovy, javafx, javafx-8

I'm currently implementing a checkers game with Groovy and JavaFX. The window that contains the board is presented once primaryStage.show() is executed and waits for an event to fire.

I have set up a sequence of functions that execute once a user clicks to make a legal move:

```
blackSquare.onMouseClicked = { e -> 
    commenceTurns(pos, view)
}
```

Conveniently this has allowed me to implement the whole game from this initial click (the AI move just executes after the user move).

However, I've now hit a problem. I need to implement multi-takes for the user and this requires me to return to the state where the board is waiting for the click event to fire. I have no idea how to accomplish this.

The basic program flow is:

```
// WAITING FOR CLICK EVENT

// CLICK EVENT CALLS:
commenceTurns()
    userTurn()
        makeMove()
        if (takeMade && canTakeFurther) {
            // EITHER JUMP TO END OF STACK OR RETURN TO WAITING STATE
        }
    computerTurn()
        makeMove()

    redrawBoard()

// END OF STACK
```

Hopefully this makes it clear what I'm looking for. Appreciate any help!